# vc6 project is tyring to link against mfc42.lib under debug mode in vs2008

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2008, hyperlink, visual-c++-6

I have my project converted from vc6 to vs2008。 When i rebuild it under "debug" mode, an link error occurs.    " fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'mfc42.lib'".
I donot know why.
why the compiler would link against 'mfc42.lib'?
Isn't it supposed to link against 'mfc42d.lib' ??
I have checked my project properties. See the followings:

C/C++:
/Od /D "WIN32" /D "_DEBUG" /D "_WINDOWS" /D "USER_CLASS=AFX_EXT_CLASS" /D "GROUP_CLASS=AFX_EXT_CLASS" /D "_VC80_UPGRADE=0x0600" /D "_AFXDLL" /D "_MBCS" /Gm /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /Yu"stdafx.h" /Fp".\Debug/SunyRTM.pch" /Fo".\Debug/" /Fd".\Debug/" /FR".\Debug/" /W3 /nologo /c /ZI /TP /errorReport:prompt

Linker:
/OUT:".._debug\ChiticRTMD.exe" /INCREMENTAL:NO /NOLOGO /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:".\Debug\ChiticRTMD.exe.intermediate.manifest" /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /DEBUG /PDB:".\Debug/ChiticRTMD.pdb" /MAP:".\Debug/ChiticRTMD.map" /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /DYNAMICBASE:NO /MACHINE:X86 /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT "..\SNetDrv\Debug\SNetDrvD.lib" "..\RdbRW2008\Debug\RdbRWD.lib" "..\IOC\Debug\IOCD.lib"

when I compared these command lines to another project converted from vc6 to vs2008 and they appear similiarly. However, that project (not current one) is able to run correctly under 'debug' mode.
It is rather confusing , who can help me?

Comment: Have you searched the source code for `#pragma comment(lib, "mfc42.lib")`? Or maybe it links another `lib` that links to `mfc42.lib`?

Comment: Yes, I did search. But i find nothing.
According to the result of "depends.exe", it was directly linked against mfc42.dll.